# Why is my List not serialized in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I am new to using JAXB and I'm struggling with a problem right now. Perhaps you can help me.

I have the following code:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Students implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Person> personList;
private int id;

// getters and setters for the attributes

}
```

and

```
 @XmlRootElement
 public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;
private int sex;

    //getters and setters for the attributes
 }
```

when I try to marshal Students this with JAXB, i only have the id-Element in the resulting string. I don't have the list (persons). Where is the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't anything special you need to do to marshal `List` properties.  Just make sure one of the following is true:

If you are using the JAXB reference implementation and have a getter for the `List` property but no setter, then you will need to annotate the getter with `@XmlElement`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Students implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Person> personList;

    @XmlElement
    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }

}
```

If you don't have a public accesssor, make sure you are using field access:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAcceesType.FIELD)
public class Students implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Person> personList;

}
```

If you have a getter and setter for the `List` property then you don't need to do anything:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Students implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
        this.person = personList;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Oddly enough your first example only works if `personList` gets rid of the `List` suffix.  Otherwise you are right on.

Comment: +1, not sure about @XmlRootElement in Person, I think it's not neccessary

Comment: @korifey - You are correct, if `Person` is never the root object, then it is not necessary.

Comment: @DMoses - The name of the field does not matter.  Are you seeing this when you annotate the field?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I guess it was a user error on my part.  But even with the getter I need `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAcceesType.FIELD)` for it to work in my tests.

Comment: @DMoses - I have corrected my answer.  If you have a getter but no setter then you need to annotate the getter with `@XmlElement`.  If you have a setter then you do not require the `@XmlElement` annotation.

Comment: Are you sure that this works this way? I have found a running sample which helped me with it: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html. If I remove every annotation except the @Xmlrootelement from every class it won't print out the serialized list (it does if i run it as in the sample on the page)

Comment: In that article by Lars Vogel he annotates the `bookList` field.  This is similar to my suggestion to annotate the property.  His example will work with the JAXB RI, but will not be guaranteed to work with all JAXB implementations (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).  Note:  I lead the EclipseLink MOXy implementation of JAXB and am a member of the JAXB 2 (JSR-222) expert group.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, try to mark class Person as @XmlType (not neccessary, I think) and all field of Students and Person classes as @XmlElement

Comment: JAXB doesn't require any annotations to marshal an object to XML.  They are only required to override the default rules:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics